# What are the minimum SAS permissions that the EventProcessorClient needs from Storage Accounts?

Tags: azure-eventhub

I couldn't find what SAS permissions I need to give, for a storage account I'm solely using to connect to Eventhub for consumption.

[picture of permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpUM3.png)

So it's stored in blobs, definitely needs to read...does it update? or Write?
Documentation only shows with connection strings.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you trying to read AVRO files from the storage account?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send

when you consume from eventhub, you need to specify a storage connection string. i'm asking what are the min permissions i should give for this connection string.

Comment: I don't know the exact set of permissions required however start with read/write/list permissions on blob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `EventProcessorClient` needs to be able to:

- List blobs in a container
- Add a new blob to a container
- Update an existing blob in the container *(metadata only)*
- Read an existing blob in the container *(metadata only)*

We generally recommend using a container dedicated to the processor and allowing the processor control over that container.